# Удержание кнопки и отправка данных

Tags: android

Нужно при удержании button1 происходило включение реле, как только я ее отпущу, прекращалось включение.

```html
package elephent.lexusaircontroll;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "bluetooth1";

    Button button1, button2;//Указываем id наших кнопок

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;

    // SPP UUID сервиса
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // MAC-адрес Bluetooth модуля
    private static String address = "98:D3:35:70:E7:67";  //Вместо “00:00” Нужно нудет ввести MAC нашего bluetooth

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.m1); //Добавляем сюда имена наших кнопок
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.m2);

        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        checkBTState();

        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  //Если будет нажата кнопка 1 то
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sendData("1");         // Посылаем цифру 1 по bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Включаем LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //выводим на устройстве сообщение
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sendData("0"); // Посылаем цифру 1 по bluetooth
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Выключаем LED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.d(TAG, "...onResume - попытка соединения...");

        // Set up a pointer to the remote node using it's address.
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

        // Two things are needed to make a connection:
        //   A MAC address, which we got above.
        //   A Service ID or UUID.  In this case we are using the
        //     UUID for SPP.
        try {
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and socket create failed: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }

        // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on
        // when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
        btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Establish the connection.  This will block until it connects.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Соединяемся...");
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "...Соединение установлено и готово к передачи данных...");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and unable to close socket during connection failure" + e2.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to server.
        Log.d(TAG, "...Создание Socket...");

        try {
            outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onResume() and output stream creation failed:" + e.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        Log.d(TAG, "...In onPause()...");

        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to flush output stream: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }

        try     {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "In onPause() and failed to close socket." + e2.getMessage() + ".");
        }
    }

    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check for Bluetooth support and then check to make sure it is turned on
        // Emulator doesn't support Bluetooth and will return null
        if(btAdapter==null) {
            errorExit("Fatal Error", "Bluetooth не поддерживается");
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "...Bluetooth включен...");
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(btAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
            }
        }
    }

    private void errorExit(String title, String message){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), title + " - " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }

    private void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        Log.d(TAG, "...Посылаем данные: " + message + "...");

        try {
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            String msg = "In onResume() and an exception occurred during write: " + e.getMessage();
            if (address.equals("98:D3:35:70:E7:67"))
                msg = msg + ".\n\nВ переменной address у вас прописан 00:00:00:00:00:00, вам необходимо прописать реальный MAC-адрес Bluetooth модуля";
            msg = msg +  ".\n\nПроверьте поддержку SPP UUID: " + MY_UUID.toString() + " на Bluetooth модуле, к которому вы подключаетесь.\n\n";

            errorExit("Fatal Error", msg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать onTouchListener - там и детектировать сам longclick и условия при убирании пальца с кнопки(onClickListener уже не нужен будет)
вот пример

```
    OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener(){
  private totalTimeDown = -1;
  private downTime = -1;
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
    if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        downTime = System.getCurrentTimeInMillis();
        return true;
    }

    if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        totalTimeDown = System.getCurrentTimeInMillis() - downTime;
        if(totalTimeDown > 500){
            //палец удержан достаточно времени для условия longClick
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```